# How to get desired dimension as Tensorflow (Keras) output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision

I'm quite new to machine learning and Tensorflow in general. I'm trying to feed the model an image of 800x800x1 dimension and trying to get an image with 800x800x1 dimension as output.

I'm trying to give the model this image,

[image: Input Image]

---

And trying to recreate the desired version given below,

[image: Output Image]

My model so far is,

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', input_shape=(800, 800, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
```

And the summary of the model,

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_70 (Conv2D)           (None, 796, 796, 32)      832       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_36 (MaxPooling (None, 398, 398, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_71 (Conv2D)           (None, 396, 396, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_37 (MaxPooling (None, 198, 198, 64)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_72 (Conv2D)           (None, 196, 196, 128)     73856     
=================================================================
Total params: 93,184
Trainable params: 93,184
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As can be seen from the last convolutional layer output, the shape is (196, 196, 128). 
So I was wondering how I can achieve the desired 800x800x1 dimension in output. I understand the problem is in my layers, but don't have the necessary knowledge to research the problem. Any thoughts or guidelines are much appreciated.

Thank you.
Have a nice day!

Comment: If you need to upsample an image you need to use transpose convolution (or as some people call deconvolution).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be exact, this is how you achieve transpose convolution in Keras. Here you should get the last layer output `(800x800x1)`. It is very important to set the `strides` in Conv2DTranspose as that's how you achieve upsampling.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(800, 800, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(64, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv2DTranspose(1, (3, 3), strides=(2,2), padding='same', activation='relu'))

model.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
That was exactly what I'm looking for.